# MySQL connector/python connection on mac

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database-connection, mysql-python

Hi guys m using  python 3.5 and MySQL connector python-2.1.5 on MacBook.
I got the error as NameError: name 'conn' is not defined.
I can't figure out how to overcome this.
I am also new to python...So pls help me guyz.
The code is given below:-

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        user = 'root',
        password='root',
        host = 'localhost',
        database='ok')
    print("it works")
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    if e.errno ==errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("usernae and password are not correct")
    elif e.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("db d.n.e")
    else:
        print(e)

cursor = conn.cursor()


conn.commit()
cursor.close()


conn.close()
```

Comment: @roganjosh i have done the identation and sorry for the "d".

Comment: Then it looks like as I expected. Your `try` is failing, so you never actually define `conn`. After the `try`/`except`, you get to `cursor = conn.cursor()` except `conn` doesn't exist. You need to solve whatever issue you have in the `try`

Comment: ohhh....now how to solve that issue in try.

Comment: i am currently blank...any help with the code will be hugely appreciated sir

Comment: Get rid of the `try`/`except` and look at the full traceback of the error i.e. let it fail and tell you why. I've done basically nothing with MySQL so I can't be sure about what you're passing to the connector.

Comment: @roganjosh the code works in php but not in python

Comment: That's irrelevant, you're using a different API. You need to look at the error that _this_ code is giving you.